# python snap7 plc and write csv

Tags: python-2.7

I write the data of my PLC in a csv file but my problem is writing line by line in my csv file and I should do data acquisition in real time fot this i used 
an infinite loop.After x time I would stockage this data and Restart again the loop automatically.

My code:

```
while(1):
    if __name__=="__main__":
        try:
            plc = c.Client()
            plc.connect('192.168.0.1',0,1)
            ReadMemory(plc,420,0,S7WLReal)
            "WriteMemory(plc,422,0,S7WLReal,6.0)"
            a=[1]
            s7 =[ReadMemory(plc,420,0,S7WLReal)]
            csv_out = open('class.csv', 'wb')
            mywriter = csv.writer(csv_out)
            rows =  zip(a, s7)
            mywriter.writerows(rows)
            csv_out.close()
            time.sleep(0.5)    
        except Snap7Exception as e:
            continue
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Format your code by prepending each line with 4 spaces

Comment: sorry :) I not understand what you want say